# WPF PreviewMouseDown event not firing for elements in Grid if clicking at the edge of row

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent

I have a Grid with rows of TextBlocks each assigned a PreviewMouseDown event handler. This event does fire when I click on the text of the TextBlocks but if I click on the edge, the event does not fire even though the canvas updates.

I've tried setting a transparent background for both the TextBlock and the Grid but that didn't help.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: use a tool like snoop and monitor the click event to find out whats swallowing it and preventing you from handling it http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/, if I recall correctly, in your case, the DatagridCell or DatagridRow may be handling it for cell/row selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by going to GridView and using the SelectionChanged handler (still doesn't catch the case if you are not clicking on a different row but that seems sufficient).